# AES-256 encryption, PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm attempting to use this encryption system with PHP.

It comes with this code from the download.

```
$salt = 'nala321';
$password = 'Alan';
 include('./crypt/Crypt/AES.php');
 $aes = new Crypt_AES();
 $aes->setKey('abcdefghijklmn');

 $size = 10 * 1024; 

***EDIT***
 $plaintext = $password.$salt;
***EDIT***

 for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
     $plaintext.= 'a';
 }
 $enc = $aes->encrypt($plaintext);
 echo $enc;
```

This results in a very long output. How do I go about storing this into mysql? 
I've looked at different ideas saying to do

***EDIT***

It returns characters like this

```
¸ÂØwÕ·›óöŽfjËëªû ÒÚCÂF I3T{öËY_Œ:4$¯Ÿ´
```

***EDIT***

```
VARCHAR(16) CHARSET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin
```

Which is for an md5 encryption password. I'm not sure if I should put down the size to

```
$size = (16*16)-1; // for 255 limit on varchar
```

Thanks for the comments to come!

Comment: You should *really* hash passwords rather than encrypt them...

Comment: It's in the sake of the question. I do salt them.

Comment: If you do encryption right you can have essentially a military grade salted hash.

Comment: its only a salt if used for one way hashing

Comment: I was referred to this function because of the military grade. Sounds good in my head :)

Comment: And you can one way hash using any encryption.

Comment: There looks to be some liberty taken with compiling the final string.  This `'./crypt/Crypt/AES.php'` library is unknown, and it looks like you're doing odd things to it.  What character encoding is used and how many characters MAX are expected in the final output string?  Aren't you able to use the regular `crypt` or `mcrypt-*` PHP functions?

Comment: the library is from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/  I just put the first /crypt/ in a special folder to organize everything.

Comment: If it's solved, post an answer, and accept it, instead of editing `*SOLVED*` into the title.

Comment: The other guy deleted his answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took out the for loop entirely.

Stored the password as just a varchar(30) and it works just fine.

The final codes looks like this

```
$password = 'Alan';
include('./crypt/Crypt/AES.php');
$aes = new Crypt_AES();
$aes->setKey('abcdefghijklmn');
$enc = $aes->encrypt($plaintext);
echo $enc;
```